# GLSL loop wrong behaviour

Tags: opengl, for-loop, glsl

We have the following piece of GLSL code:

```
#version 120
#define LIGHT_COUNT 2
...
varying vec3 v_light_tan[LIGHT_COUNT];
varying float v_attenuation[LIGHT_COUNT];

uniform vec3 light_position[LIGHT_COUNT];

void main(void) {
  ...
for ( int index = 0; index < LIGHT_COUNT; index++ )
{
    float distance = length( light_position[index] - world_pos );
    v_attenuation[index] = 1.0 / ( 1.0 + 0.05 * distance * distance);
    vec3 light_loc  = vec3(nv_m_model_inv * vec4 (light_position[index], 1.0) );
    vec3 light_dir_loc = normalize( nv_position - light_loc );
    v_light_tan[index] = vec3(
        dot( nv_tangent.xyz, light_dir_loc ),
        dot( bitangent, light_dir_loc ),
        dot( nv_normal, light_dir_loc )
    );  
}
```

I've read a lot about problems with loops, so I went with a hardcoded loop. But even this simple code seems to fail. The above works for `LIGHT_COUNT = 1`, but for `2`, the value of v_attenuation[0] gets corrupted. Surprisingly, changing the code to:

```
for ( int index = 0; index < LIGHT_COUNT; index++ )
{
    float distance = length( light_position[index] - world_pos );
    v_attenuation[index] = 1.0 / ( 1.0 + 0.05 * distance * distance);
}

for ( int index = 0; index < LIGHT_COUNT; index++ )
{
    vec3 light_loc  = vec3(nv_m_model_inv * vec4 (light_position[index], 1.0) );
    vec3 light_dir_loc = normalize( nv_position - light_loc );
    v_light_tan[index] = vec3(
        dot( nv_tangent.xyz, light_dir_loc ),
        dot( bitangent, light_dir_loc ),
        dot( nv_normal, light_dir_loc )
    );  
}
```

... ergo two separate loops, works. Adding `#pragma optionNV(unroll all)` works as well.

Both of those seem hacky though, for something that is such a simple loop example. Is GLSL **that** broken, or did I miss some rule or guideline of writing GLSL loops?

If relevant:

```
OpenGL Vendor       : NVIDIA Corporation
OpenGL Renderer     : GeForce GTX 690/PCIe/SSE2
OpenGL Version      : 4.4.0
OpenGL GLSL Version : 4.40 NVIDIA via Cg compiler
```

Comment: You should not be writing to input variables in fragment shaders. Frankly I do not even know why you are writing to `v_attenuation [...]` in the first place, that value is never used anywhere in the shaders you have pasted.

Comment: Can you post your vertex ***and*** fragment shaders? In GLSL 1.20, you can run into issues indexing uniforms using non-const expressions (e.g. loop control variables, so `light_position [index]` could create issues) in the fragment stage. In the vertex stage, it is *supposed* to work.

Comment: "Is GLSL that broken". The version 1.2 is deprecated for 6 years now. So yeah, it may be broken. I don't know what is your objective using a version that old of GLSL while your hardware is quite up to date. If the target is embedded device, it is still flawed as the only existing version of GLSL for OpenGL ES 2.0 is the 1.0 that is a mix of the desktop version 1.0, 1.1 and 1.2.

Comment: 33% of my potential userbase still uses hardware that is GL 2.1 max, so I need to support it. However, even creating a 3.3+ context, and changing version to 330 still produces the same behavior. I use a common subset of GLES 2.0 and GL2.1. @AndonM.Coleman this is the vertex shader.

Comment: Can you post the fragment shader anyway? NV compiles shaders in two phases (other implementations probably do too, but I cannot speak on their behalf), the first time it compiles your shader it is to determine the inputs/outputs, the second time is during linking. At link-time, the compiler thinks it's smart enough to eliminate unused variables and it does code optimization based on this. If your vertex and fragment shaders both access the varying array dynamically it can mess with things. This is clearly an issue with code optimization if forcing the compiler to unroll fixes the problem.